# A Question Regarding the Differences of Terminologies and Theorems Related to Polynomial Division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, algorithms, roots, factoring

This will be a long post and there will be a TL;DR at the end.

I've recently been re-reading topics on polynomial division to brush up my knowledge on them but sometimes I get a little confused and conflate some of the terms because they seem to mean similar things and I'e seen some people online use them interchangeably so ***I wanted to ask on the differences between the following terms and whether or not my understanding and summary of them is correct***.

#### • [**Euclidean Division of Polynomials**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division):

Essentially, the polynomial analogue to [**Euclidean Division of Integers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) but instead of
$$ a = bq + r \tag{$a, b, q, r \in \mathbb{Z}\,$, $b\neq 0\,$, $0 \leq r < |b|$,} $$
where $a$ is the *dividend*, $b$ is the *divisor*, $q$ is the *quotient*, and $r$ is the *remainder*,

we have
$$ f(x) = g(x)Q(x) + R(x) \tag{$g(x) \neq 0\,$, either $R = 0$ or $\deg(R) < \deg(g)$,} $$
where $f(x)$ is the *dividend polynomial*, $g(x)$ is the *divisor polynomial*, $Q(x)$ is the *quotient polynomial*, and $R(x)$ is the *remainder polynomial*.

#### • [**Polynomial Long Division**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division):

Polynomial long division is an algorithm that implements the Euclidean division of polynomials for dividing a polynomial by another polynomial of the same or lower degree similar to the arithmetic technique of [**Long Division**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) in which the variable $x$ is replaced (in base $10$) by the specific number $10$.

***Examples***:

$\mathbf{1.}$ The answer to "Find the quotient and the remainder of the polynomial division of $x^3 - 2x^2 - 4$, the *dividend*, by $x-3$, the *divisor*." would be the following.

[image: Example 1 Using Polynomial Long Division]

The polynomial above the bar is the *quotient* $Q(x)$, and the number left over, $5$, is the *remainder* $R$.

Hence the quotient and remainder are:
$$
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) &= x^2 + x + 3, \\
    R &= 5.
\end{align*}
$$

$\mathbf{2.}$ The answer to "Find the quotient and the remainder of the polynomial division of $x^3 - 12x^2 - 42$, the *dividend*, by $x^2 + x - 3$, the *divisor*." would be the following.

[image: Example 2 Using Polynomial Long Division]

Hence the quotient and remainder are:
$$
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) &= x - 13, \\
    R(x) &= 16x - 81.
\end{align*}
$$

$\mathbf{3.}$ The answer to "Find the quotient and the remainder of the polynomial division of $6x^3 + 5x^2 - 7$, the *dividend*, by $3x^2 - 2x - 1$, the *divisor*." would be the following.

[image: Example 3 Using Polynomial Long Division]

Hence the quotient and remainder are:
$$
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) &= 2x + 3, \\
    R(x) &= 8x - 4.
\end{align*}
$$

#### • [**Polynomial Synthetic Division**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division):

Polynomial synthetic division is a method for manually performing Euclidean division of polynomials, with less writing and fewer calculations than long division.

***Examples***:

$\mathbf{1.}$ The answer to "Find the quotient and the remainder of the polynomial division of $x^3 - 2x^2 - 4$, the *dividend*, by $x-3$ (whose root is $x = 3$), the *divisor*." would be the following.

[image: Example 1 Using Polynomial Synthetic Division]

Hence the quotient and remainder are:
$$
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) &= x^2 + x + 3, \\
    R &= 5.
\end{align*}
$$

$\mathbf{2.}$ The answer to "Find the quotient and the remainder of the polynomial division of $x^3 - 12x^2 - 42$, the *dividend*, by $x^2 + x - 3$, the *divisor*." would be the following.

Negate the coefficients of the divisor and write in every coefficient but the first one on the left in an upward right diagonal.

[image: Example 2 Using Polynomial Synthetic Division]

Count the terms to the left of the bar. Since there are two, the remainder has degree one ($\deg(R) < \deg(g)$) and this is the two right-most terms under the bar.

Hence the quotient and remainder are:
$$
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) &= x - 13, \\
    R(x) &= 16x - 81.
\end{align*}
$$

$\mathbf{3.}$ The answer to "Find the quotient and the remainder of the polynomial division of $6x^3 + 5x^2 - 7$, the *dividend*, by $3x^2 - 2x - 1$, the *divisor*." would be the following.

Negate the coefficients of the divisor and write in every coefficient but the first one on the left in an upward right diagonal.

[image: Example 3 Using Polynomial Synthetic Division]

Note the extra row at the bottom. This is used to write values found by dividing the "dropped" values by the leading coefficient of $g(x)$ (in this case, indicated by the $\div\,3$; note that, unlike the rest of the coefficients of $g(x)$, the sign of this number is not changed).

Count the terms to the left of the bar. Since there are two, the remainder has degree one ($\deg(R) < \deg(g)$) and this is the two right-most terms under the bar (the values of the remainder are not divided by the leading coefficient of the divisor).

Hence the quotient and remainder are:
$$
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) &= 2x + 3, \\
    R(x) &= 8x - 4.
\end{align*}
$$

#### • [**Gauss's Lemma for Polynomials**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)):

The **primitive content** of a polynomial $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$ is defined to be $\gcd(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$.
The **primitive part** of such a polynomial is the quotient of the polynomial by its content, i.e., $\dfrac{f(x)}{\gcd(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)}$. A polynomial is **primitive** if its content equals $1$. Thus the primitive part of a polynomial is a primitive polynomial.

Gauss's lemma asserts that the product of two primitive polynomials is primitive, i.e, for $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$, $g(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + \cdots + b_m x^m$, and $f(x)g(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + \cdots + c_{m+n} x^{m+n}$, we have

$$ \gcd(c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{m+n}) = 1 \iff (\gcd(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 1) \land (\gcd(b_0, b_1, \ldots, b_m) = 1). $$

***I still don't understand the relation to the following Rational Root Theorem even after reading the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem#Proof_using_Gauss%27_lemma).***

#### • [**Rational Root Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

The rational root theorem, a special case (for a single linear factor) of Gauss's lemma on the factorization of polynomials, states that for each rational solution $x = \frac{p}{q}$ of a polynomial equation
$$a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 = 0$$
(with integer coefficients $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a_0, a_n \neq 0$), written in lowest terms so that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, satisfies:

$1.$ $p$ is an integer factor of $a_0$.

$2.$ $q$ is an integer factor of $a_n$.

***Example***:

Every rational root of the polynomial
$$ 3x^3 - 5x^2 + 5x - 2 $$
must be among the numbers symbolically indicated by:
$$ \pm\frac{1,2}{1,3} = \pm\left\{1, 2, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right\} $$
These $8$ root candidates $x = r$ can be tested by evaluating $P(r)$

[image: The Efficient Process of Rational Root Theorem]

***I still don't understand the justification of the efficient process above (and is it generalized?)***

#### • [**Polynomial Remainder Theorem (or little Bézout's theorem)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)

The polynomial remainder theorem or little Bézout's theorem states that for the Euclidean division of polynomials form

$$ f(x) = g(x)Q(x) + R(x) = (x - r)Q(x) + R,$$

the remainder, $R$, of the division of the polynomial $f(x)$ by a linear polynomial $g(x) = x - r$ is equal to $f(r)$.

#### • [**Factor Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

Factor theorem is a special case of the polynomial remainder theorem (when $R = 0$) which states
$$ f(x) \text{ has a factor } (x - r) \iff f(r) = 0. \tag{i.e., $r$ is a root} $$

#### • [**Horner's Method (or Horner's Scheme)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)

Horner's method or Horner's scheme is an algorithm for polynomial evaluation based on **Horner's rule**:
$$
a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + a_n x^n = a_0 + x\left( a_1 + x\left( a_2 + \cdots + x\left(a_{n-1} + a_n\right) \right) \right)
$$
and essentially uses polynomial synthetic division (divide $f(x)$ by $g(x) = x - x_0$) and applies the polynomial remainder theorem ($f(x_0) = R$).

Alternatively, **Horner's method** also refers to a method for approximating the roots of polynomials, described by Horner in 1819. It is a variant of the Newton–Raphson method made more efficient for hand calculation by the application of Horner's rule.

[image: Polynomial Root Finding Using Horner's Method]

#### • [**Ruffini's Rule**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule)

Ruffini's rule is a method for computation of the Euclidean division of a polynomial and is a special case of polynomial synthetic division in which the divisor is a linear factor $(x - r)$.

## • TL;DR

$1.$ **Euclidean Division of Polynomials**: $f(x) = g(x) Q(x) + R(x)$.

$2.$ **Polynomial Long Division**: Long division but for polynomials.

$3.$ **Polynomial Synthetic Division**: The division part of Horner's method or Horner's scheme.

$4.$ **Gauss's Lemma for Polynomials**: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are primitive polynomials over the integers, their product $f(x)g(x)$ is also primitive.

$5.$ **Rational Root Theorem**: Each possible rational solution of $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n = 0$ is $x = \frac{p}{q}$ where $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ and $p \mid a_0 \;\land\; q \mid a_n$.

$6.$ **Polynomial Remainder Theorem**: $f(x) = (x - r) Q(x) + R \iff f(r) = R$.

$7.$ **Factor Theorem**: $f(x) = (x - r) Q(x) \iff f(r) = 0$.

$8.$ **Horner's Method (or Horner's Scheme)**:

a. *Polynomial evaluation* (synthetic division + polynomial remainder theorem)

b. *Polynomial root-finding* (initial educated guess of $x_0$ where $f(x_0) = 0$ + Newton–Raphson method + Horner's method + iteration)

$9.$ **Ruffini's Rule**: A special case of synthetic division in which the divisor is a linear factor $(x - r)$.

***Are my understanding of each of them accurate?***

Thank you if you've managed to read this far and I would be grateful for any answers I might receive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's much too diffuse - even the tl;dr is too long. If you post a question with a particular puzzle you have resolving two polynomial theorems or algorithms we might be able to help.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @EthanBolker here - this is way too long and a lot to wade through.